# Sum of the variations of a function over a countable partition

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, functions

Assume that $F$ is a real continuous function of bounded variation over an interval $[a,b]$.
Let $(I_i)_i$ be a countable set of non-overlapping closed intervals of $[a,b]$ whose union is $[a,b]$. Set $I_i = [u_i, v_i]$.

Let $(I'_i)_i$ be another such countable set, with $I'_i= [u'_i, v'_i]$.
Without care, one may think that 
$\sum_i (F(v_i)-F(u_i)) = F(b)-F(a) = \sum_i (F(v'_i)-F(u'_i))$.

This leads to the following questions:

Question 1: Is it possible that $\sum_i (F(v_i)-F(u_i))$ and $\sum_i (F(v'_i)-F(u'_i))$ converge to two different values? (obviously these sums converge since $F$ is of bounded variation).

I suspect that this is possible, hence the next question:

Question 2: If it is furthermore assumed that the sequences $(|I_i|)_i$ and $(|I'_i|)_i$ are non increasing, is it possible that $\sum_i (F(v_i)-F(u_i))$ and $\sum_i (F(v'_i)-F(u'_i))$ converge to two different values ?

Answer (score 0):

The collection $I_i$ is a partition of $[a,b]$. As you have correctly noted, for any partition we always have
$$\sum_{i}(F(v_i) - F(u_i)) = F(b) - F(a)$$
because the values of $F$ at the intermediate partition points cancel out. So it doesn't make sense to talk about that sum "converging".

What I think you are talking about is the sum
$$\sum_{i}\vert F(v_i) - F(u_i) \vert.$$
This sum is attempting to estimate the arc length of the graph of $F$ by straight lines. Since $F$ is of bounded variation, by definition the above sum "converges" in the sense that its supremum over all possible partitions of $[a,b]$ is finite, i.e.
$$\sup_{(I_i) \textrm{ is a partition of } [a,b]}\sum_i \vert F(v_i) - F(u_i) \vert = M < \infty.$$
The quantity $M$ is called the total variation of $F$ over $[a,b]$, denoted by $T_F(a,b)$. It is also the arc length of the curve. In fact, bounded variation is a necessary and sufficient condition for arc length to be well defined.

Comment: Ethan: thank you for trying answering me. No, it is not obvious at all that $\sum_i (F(v_i)-F(u_i)) = F(b) - F(a)$; this is only the case if the set of intervals $I_i$ is finite. Note also that this is not a partition of $[a,b]$, but a set of non-overlapping closed intervals covering $[a,b]$ (meaning they can intersect only at their end points $u_i$ or $v_i$). Please, change your answer (if you can) or remove this one, otherwise someone will have to down vote it. Hag Sameah.